# Azure Virtual Machines stuck in Starting mode

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

This morning I found 5 of my Azure Virtual machines to be stuck in Starting mode. 
All other VMs are working ok.

I managed to stop the VMs using the Azure command shell and then start them again but they are still stuck in starting mode with no end in sight.

It has now been over 5 1/2 hours and still stuck in starting mode.

I have contacted Microsoft support but they are taking hours to respond :(((

The Azure Status page doesn't show anything is wrong in my region.

Has anybody else experiencing this problem?

Comment: Beginning to regret moving to VMs :((

Comment: same here =\ I think we can just stay waiting

Comment: I restarted the cloud service the virtual machines belong to. That did the trick for me.

Comment: How did you restart the cloud to which the VMs are attached - did your public IP change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've had the same issue and it's linked to a big issue Azure is having this morning.

The trick we used in order to get the instance running again is:
1. stop the VMs via Powershell
2. change the size of the vm and back (preferably from A to D as this is different hardware)
3. start the VM

We also have people complaining about RDP not working where reboots fixed the problem.

Comment: Finally got a response from MS after 9 hours! Told me to resize the VMs. I can confirm that resizing (just like you advised) has now fixed the problem.

Comment: I tried resizing a vm and it changed the ip address. Were you able to resize without changing the ip address?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently some problems with Azure, including the VM service. Also the status page does not reflect all of the problems. Here you have to keep in mind that this page also show impacts affecting most of the service customers. It does not reflect minor outages to single customers. You should keep an eye at the Azure blog which possibly gives a statement related to the current problems.

Comment: I check the azure blog but doesn't have any status information, what is the address to which you refer?

Comment: Most of the information are found on [this blog](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/). It can take some time before they publish some information (normally after they have found the problem and a solution for it).

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is a redeploy of the Virtual Machine within the Azure Portal whenever it gets stuck at "Starting...". Altho it takes half an hour to redeploy, it solves the issue. More details [here](https://blog.nicolaayan.com/2018/01/azure-virtual-machine-boot-diagnostics-failed-to-get-contents-of-blob/).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I experienced and what I did is I resized Virtual Machine's Disk Size, You can go for increasing the whole VM size / power but for me the Disk size fixed it, probably it was updating and the disk file ran out.